# Newlines in BSD sed vs gsed

Tags: sed, gnu, newlines, bsd

The sed, which comes with FreeBSD 11.2 p7, gives:

```
 $ seq 10 | sed 'N; l; D; p'
1$
2$
2$
3$
3$
4$
4$
5$
5$
6$
6$
7$
7$
8$
8$
9$
9$
10$
```

While gsed (GNU sed 4.7) gives for the same script:

```
$ seq 10 | gsed 'N; l; D; p'
1\n2$
2\n3$
3\n4$
4\n5$
5\n6$
6\n7$
7\n8$
8\n9$
9\n10$
10
```

How can we explain this difference in behavior?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

BSD `sed`, when using `l` to output characters in  a visually unambiguous form, does not output newlines in  a visually unambiguous form.

From [sed(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/sed) on OpenBSD:

```
 [2addr]l
         (The letter ell.)  Write the pattern space to the standard output
         in a visually unambiguous form.  This form is as follows:

               backslash          \\
               alert              \a
               backspace          \b
               form-feed          \f
               carriage-return    \r
               tab                \t
               vertical tab       \v
```

(note lack of mentioning of newlines).

GNU `sed`, however, includes newlines in the set of characters to display unambiguously.  It does this as an extension to the set of characters that the [POSIX standard for `sed`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html) mentions (which is the set that BSD `sed` uses). GNU `sed` behaves this way even if `--posix` is used on the command line.

GNU `sed` also outputs `10` twice, while BSD `sed` does not.  Running GNU `sed` with `POSIXLY_CORRECT` set or with `--posix` will make it output `10` only once, like BSD `sed` does.

This is because GNU `sed` by default ignores the part of POSIX definition of the `sed` `N` command that says

> If no next line of input is available, the `N` command verb shall branch to the end of the script and quit without starting a new cycle or copying the pattern space to standard output.

Note also that the `p` in your `sed` program never executes, as `D` starts a new cycle.

Comment: Another difference is 10 being displayed once with BSD sed, and this time GNU sed behaves like BSD sed with POSIXLY_CORRECT. That's why you generally want to use `$!N` instead of `N` when `-n` is not enabled.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks. I did not notice that difference at first.

Comment: Note that ast-open's sed behaves like GNU sed wrt `\n` displayed by `l`. I suspect the POSIX requirement is an oversight here (they say it's not applicable which doesn't make sense here, I suspect they say that because the pattern space normally doesn't contain newline by default but overlook the fact that it can be added by N, G, s...; if they wanted to require the original sed behaviour, they would have said something like newline shall be output literally or something like that)